# Building a docker container returns an error

Tags: docker

I am a new docker user. I was using Docker Desktop to build 
a Linux Container in a Windows 10 64-bit machine. The container host 
a web-service.

When the building process run to this Dockfile scripts:

```
"RUN $INSTALLDIR/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites/install_prerequisites.sh"
```

it returns the following error:

```
"src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpp:910:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory"
```

I have tried in a different clean machine but still got the same error.

I did it successfully once, but then keep failure.

Could anybody have any ideas or suggestion?

Comment: Can you add your whole Dockerfile to the question (they're usually fairly short)?  That error generally means you're missing some relevant C header files.

Comment: Two observations:
 1. It looks like you're missing Python headers. They should be available in the package "python3-dev"
 2. You're building from source. You probably don't want that. Try updating your pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Thanks, Richard! I will try this idea.